# Personal Proxy for Postfix SMTP?

Tags: email, postfix, proxy, email-server

I have my own Postfix instance running on my server to send and receive letters. It is configured to reject connections from "unknown" hosts. It's okay and I would not change this to keep a minimal spam protection.

However, it makes me harder to send letters from the local machine, since I am using Windows client (TheBat) and my machine is above the router that have no hostname and has a dynamic IP also. So when I'm trying to send letters from the local machine, Postfix rejects this.

To fix this I would try to use something like simple Proxy on the port different than 25 that will allow me to send letters via it. This proxy will redirect all incoming letters to Postfix port 25 and it will have a hostname, so Postfix will not reject letters.

Will this model work? I am not sure there is no better solution, because I guess the problem is popular.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just give it a IP address range (e.g. 192.168.0.0/24) as the list of known hosts that matches the range handed out via DHCP on your LAN?

Failing that have it accept connections that authenticate with a username/password no matter which host they connect from.

Also mail submission should probably be already running on port 587 rather than port 25

Comment: Thanks! I've enabled "submission" in postfix master.cf and changed port to 587 in my email client and now emails going out well.

Comment: Making IP address range would not work, since I am far from the server and my IP range could be very different too (it's not a local IP).

Comment: Then submission with authentication is the right solution, not a proxy